# nested defs not working

Tags: python

What do i need to add to the second def statement in order for it to work?

```
def main():
    # the user has to choose a picture and then he is asked to
    pic = makePicture(pickAFile())

    # the user is asked to select a color that he wants to remove from a picture
    color = requestString("Which color would you like to remove?")
    show(pic)

    # whats wrong with this last part that doesn't make the modifications to the picture
    def RemoveColor(pic, color):
        r = red
        g = green
        b = blue
        for px in getPixels(pic):
            setRed(px, 0)

        for px in getPixels(pic):
            setGreen(px, 0)

        for px in getPixels(pic):
            setBlue(px, 0)

    repaint(pic)
```

Comment: In order for anyone to be able to help you, you'll need to describe your specific problem. This code snippet references a lot of undefined functions.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you may want to give [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's guide to style, a read.

Comment: you define removeColor but you never call the function.

Answer (score 0):

here I take out `RemoveColor` function from your `main` function, and I call it from inside `main`

```
def RemoveColor(pic, color):
    r = red
    g = green
    b = blue
    for px in getPixels(pic):
        setRed(px, 0)

    for px in getPixels(pic):
        setGreen(px, 0)

    for px in getPixels(pic):
        setBlue(px, 0)

def main():
    # the user has to choose a picture and then he is asked to
    pic = makePicture(pickAFile())

    # the user is asked to select a color that he wants to remove from a picture
    color = requestString("Which color would you like to remove?")
    show(pic)

    RemoveColor(pic, color) # HERE I'M CALLING RemoveColor
    repaint(pic)
```

Comment: @furins.. thanks for the post. i have one more question. why is RemoveColor(pic, color) not working, the program goes through the "for" statements but it takes away all the color and repaints it in black. how do i get it to remove only the color that was requested?

Comment: @EsJe please let me know wich libraries are you using and I'll try to answer... what library/module defines `getPixel`?

Comment: @fusins i don't understand what do you mean by modules or library since i am new to programming. do you think you could be a little more specific?

Comment: do you write "import [some module]" somewhere before the code you have shown us? May you publish your entire code? However, this is second question not related to the "nested def" problem:  you should start a new question in stackoverflow in order to receive the help of the community

Comment: At a first glance, however, I see that in your removecolor function you never check if the pixel in the for loop has the desired color, you simply replace all the pixels and you are not using the color attribute at all.